# Missing "Create Unit Tests..." menu item in Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper, visual-studio-power-tools

I'm using Vs2010 Ultimate

Recently I've installed:

- Resharper -http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/index.html
- VS2010 power tools - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasonz/archive/2010/06/07/announcing-vs2010-productivity-power-tools-and-modeling-feature-packs.aspx

Since installing one of these two things (not sure which) I've lost my right-click menu to allow me to quickly create unit tests within solution explorer

Does anyone know how to redisplay that menu item?

- I've looked high and low for it through settings
- I've already tried disabling the "hide overriden VS menu items" option in R#

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I have installed Resharper. It does not create problems and hence try removing the powertoys.

Comment: Thanks - if there's no-one with a quick fix, then I will try uninstalling things - but I'd love to keep both tools if possible (the add reference dialog in the power tools is such a time saver)

Comment: I've got both installed and I still see Add->New Test in the right-click menu on a project in the solution explorer.

Comment: I wonder if you found a solution. I could always right click in a class and choose `Create Unittest`...

Comment: No - it was something to do with the project... not the plugins...

Answer (score 0):

I see you were using VS2010. I have the same set of tools and never had an issue. Is it SKU problem? Unfortunately in VS2012 it's a known "issue" that VS team didn't address since RC: [Where is the "Create Unit Tests" selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547055/where-is-the-create-unit-tests-selection).