# Where can I find the create unit tests command in Ms visual basic 2010 express?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, unit-testing

I am using Microsoft Visual Basic 2010 Express and I can't find the 'create test unit' command in the context menu.

I have tried this link: [Where is the "Create Unit Tests" selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547055/where-is-the-create-unit-tests-selection) and did not get solution. Please help.

Comment: Afaik Visual Studio Express versions do not support Microsoft UnitTest (MSTest) projects - you need the Professional/Premium/Ultimate SKU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm struggling to find a definitive product comparison link, but I'm pretty sure that Visual Basic Express 2010 does not support Unit Tests, at least the 2008 edition definitely doesn't:

http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/f/e/5feb6914-bcdf-432f-81c7-e386812b086a/VisualStudio2008-ProductComparison-v1.08.pdf

The link you posted refers to fuller Visual Studio 2010 versions.

Upgrade, or look into possible 3rd party plugins for your edition which can unit test.