# Autocreate unit test project for new class library

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, projects-and-solutions

Is there an option to auto create a unit test project whenever I create a class library in Visual Studio 2013?

I know it's trivial to do so manually but I have just created a new solution with 7 distinct projects and the only one that does this automatically is an ASP.Net MVC project. So there goes another couple of minutes of life creating the unit test proj for the class libraries and adding references to the class library under test.

Also it would be great if I could set up a convention so that the unit test is created in another directory rather than the same directory as my class library source as I use:

> main > source > source

for code and

> main > test > source

for test re: revision control directory structure.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547055/where-is-the-create-unit-tests-selection) question.

Comment: Thanks it looks like most is not 2013 relevant and/or about creating projects. Most is about generating a unit test for an existing class whereas Im looking to automagically and by convention just create me some unit test projects on creating a new class library project.