# Right click in Visual Studio 2013 not showing create unit test

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

Right Click (which shows Context Menu) doesn't show Create Unit Test. I tried this, but it fails:

[image: Options in my VS doesn't show Create Unit Test as well.]

Have you guys got any idea what I can do?

P.S. I have Visual Studio Professional 2013.

Comment: Where exactly are you right clicking? Context is everything.

Comment: @OmegaMan I use Right Click on method name

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio 2013 are you using?

Comment: @OmegaMan as I said VS Pro 2013 - if this what you need.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this feature was missing from VS2012 and VS2013, but I'm not sure if it was then added back in (it is now present in VS2017, assuming you're targeting the full .net framework rather than Core or Standard).

There was **a lot** of discussion of VS2012's missing context menu option [in this question by Houman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547055/where-is-the-create-unit-tests-selection?rq=1) and there was also some discussion of VS2013 in the answers for that question. I'm not sure if you've seen that, but if not I'd try working through the suggestions there (there's way too many to reproduce them again here).

Answer (score 0):

I know I am very late in answering, but this SO post could be of help to you.
[Where is the "Create Unit Tests" selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547055/where-is-the-create-unit-tests-selection)