# How do I get the context menu "Create Unit Tests" when working with ASP .NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, xunit.net, vs-unit-testing-framework

After updating Visual Studio 2015 to Update 3 and install ASP .NET Core, I created a new Web API project.

When I right-click at a method, I no longer see the context menu "Create Unit Tests".

[image: Context Menu]

Also, is there a project template to quickly create a new Unit Test project using ASP .NET Core? I found [the instruction](https://docs.asp.net/en/dev/testing/unit-testing.html) from ASP .NET documentation web site, but I don't want to concern about it every time I want to create a new unit test project.

The top xUnit NuGet package cannot be installed to a new ASP .NET Core class library project.
[image: xUnit NuGet package]

Comment: From which version did you upgrade?  Afaik that "create unit tests" item has been gone for years.

Comment: Full VS integration of unit testing will not come before VS "15" is out. You can use some xunit support by reading their homepage.

Answer (score 0):

You could check this SO answer out to get "Create unit tests" context menu back.
[Where is the "Create Unit Tests" selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547055/where-is-the-create-unit-tests-selection)